# C++ code doesn't compile because of an error

Tags: c++

I'm currently solving problems for my high school final exam at programming in C++. I tried solving a problem in CodeBlocks, but it gives me this error at line 13:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

I don't see what is wrong.

The problem is about removing the last consonant from a string. The string is `"mare frig saci"` and it should produce `"mare frig sai"`, removing the last `'c'`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[256];
    int i;
    cin.get(s,256);
    for(i=strlen(s)-1;i=0;i--)
    {
        if(strchr(s,"aeiou")!=0)
            strcpy(s+i+1,s+i-1);
    }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag C++ code with "c", also see the description of the tags you apply.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of [strchr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) ? It clearly says the second parameter should be an int, but you gave a const char* ("aeiou").

Comment: `i=0;` in the for loop is not a comparison, it is an assignment. Use `==`/`!=` for comparison

Comment: In the for loop you are assigning the value 0 to `i` instead of comparing it. The `strchr` function expects a character (int) as a second argument, but you are giving a string (const char *).

Comment: If you intend to use C++, I suggest to use `std::string` instead of C-Style strings.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems:

1. `i=0` is not a condition, it's an assignment. `i>=0` is probably what you're looking for here
2. `strchr` take in a `string` and `char` (1), and return a **pointer** (2), not an `int` to be compared. Both (1) and (2) condition isn't sastified. In any case, `strchr` is not ideal to use here.

I recommended using `std::string` (as it's more easy to use and standard in C++) and `std::string::find_last_of`, which find the last character in string inside a set of characters, exactly what you wanted here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s; getline(std::cin, s);
    string cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";

    size_t pos = s.find_last_of(cons);
    if (pos != string::npos) //if a consonant is found
    {
        s.erase(pos, 1);
    }
    cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- [`std::strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr) - The valid signatures are

  ```
  const char* strchr( const char* str, int ch );
        char* strchr(       char* str, int ch );
  ```

  So, you are supplying it with the wrong things.
- [`std::strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) - "*The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap*" - so you can't use `std::strcpy` to move the end of the string to the new place. Instead use [`std::memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove).
- Since the string you mention contains a space at the end, you must add space to the list of vowels.
- You assign `0` to `i` instead of checking it's value.

Example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char s[256] = " mare frig saci ";

    for (size_t len = strlen(s), i = len; i-- > 0;) {   // corrected loop
        if (std::strchr("aeiou ", s[i]) == nullptr) {   // corrected check
            std::memmove(s + i, s + i + 1, len - i);    // corrected move
            break;                                      // and break out
        }
    }
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```